# Find Yesterday's High Price by Merging Two DF's on Datetime and Date Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ohlc

I'm trying to merge two df's, one df has a `datetime` column, and the other has just a `date` column. My application for this is to find yesterday's `high` price using an OHLC dataset. I've attached some starter code below, but I'll describe what I'm looking for.

Given this `intraday` dataset:

```
                  time  current_intraday_high
0  2022-02-11 09:00:00                      1
1  2022-02-11 10:00:00                      2
2  2022-02-11 11:00:00                      3
3  2022-02-11 12:00:00                      4
4  2022-02-11 13:00:00                      5
5  2022-02-14 09:00:00                      6
6  2022-02-14 10:00:00                      7
7  2022-02-14 11:00:00                      8
8  2022-02-14 12:00:00                      9
9  2022-02-14 13:00:00                     10
10 2022-02-15 09:00:00                     11
11 2022-02-15 10:00:00                     12
12 2022-02-15 11:00:00                     13
13 2022-02-15 12:00:00                     14
14 2022-02-15 13:00:00                     15
15 2022-02-16 09:00:00                     16
16 2022-02-16 10:00:00                     17
17 2022-02-16 11:00:00                     18
18 2022-02-16 12:00:00                     19
19 2022-02-16 13:00:00                     20
```

...and this `daily` dataframe:

```
        time  daily_high
0 2022-02-11           5
1 2022-02-14          10
2 2022-02-15          15
3 2022-02-16          20
```

...how can I merge them together, and have each row of the `intraday` dataframe contain the previous (business) day's high price, like so:

```
                  time  current_intraday_high  yesterdays_high
0  2022-02-11 09:00:00                      1              NaN
1  2022-02-11 10:00:00                      2              NaN
2  2022-02-11 11:00:00                      3              NaN
3  2022-02-11 12:00:00                      4              NaN
4  2022-02-11 13:00:00                      5              NaN
5  2022-02-14 09:00:00                      6              5.0
6  2022-02-14 10:00:00                      7              5.0
7  2022-02-14 11:00:00                      8              5.0
8  2022-02-14 12:00:00                      9              5.0
9  2022-02-14 13:00:00                     10              5.0
10 2022-02-15 09:00:00                     11             10.0
11 2022-02-15 10:00:00                     12             10.0
12 2022-02-15 11:00:00                     13             10.0
13 2022-02-15 12:00:00                     14             10.0
14 2022-02-15 13:00:00                     15             10.0
15 2022-02-16 09:00:00                     16             15.0
16 2022-02-16 10:00:00                     17             15.0
17 2022-02-16 11:00:00                     18             15.0
18 2022-02-16 12:00:00                     19             15.0
19 2022-02-16 13:00:00                     20             15.0
```

(Note the `NaN`'s at the top because we don't have any data for Feb 10, 2022 from the intraday dataset, and see how each row contains the `intraday` data, plus the PREVIOUS day's max "`high`" price.)

Minimal reproducible example code below:

```
import pandas as pd


###################################################
# CREATE MOCK INTRADAY DATAFRAME
###################################################
intraday_date_time = [
    "2022-02-11 09:00:00",
                "2022-02-11 10:00:00",
                "2022-02-11 11:00:00",
                "2022-02-11 12:00:00",
                "2022-02-11 13:00:00",
    "2022-02-14 09:00:00",
                "2022-02-14 10:00:00",
                "2022-02-14 11:00:00",
                "2022-02-14 12:00:00",
                "2022-02-14 13:00:00",
    "2022-02-15 09:00:00",
                "2022-02-15 10:00:00",
                "2022-02-15 11:00:00",
                "2022-02-15 12:00:00",
                "2022-02-15 13:00:00",
    "2022-02-16 09:00:00",
                "2022-02-16 10:00:00",
                "2022-02-16 11:00:00",
                "2022-02-16 12:00:00",
                "2022-02-16 13:00:00",
]
intraday_date_time = pd.to_datetime(intraday_date_time)
intraday_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": intraday_date_time,
        "current_intraday_high": [x for x in range(1, 21)],
    },
)
print(intraday_df)
# intraday_df.to_csv('intradayTEST.csv', index=True)


###################################################
# AGGREGATE/UPSAMPLE TO DAILY DATAFRAME
###################################################
# Aggregate to business days using intraday_df
agg_dict = {'current_intraday_high': 'max'}
daily_df = intraday_df.set_index('time').resample('B').agg(agg_dict).reset_index()
daily_df.rename(columns={"current_intraday_high": "daily_high"}, inplace=True)
print(daily_df)
# daily_df.to_csv('dailyTEST.csv', index=True)


###################################################
# MERGE THE TWO DATAFRAMES
###################################################
# Need to merge the daily dataset to the intraday dataset, such that,
# any row on the newly merged/joined/concat'd dataset will have:
# 1. The current intraday datetime in the 'time' column
# 2. The current 'intraday_high' value
# 3. The PREVIOUS DAY's 'daily_high' value
# This doesn't work as the daily_df just gets appended to the bottom
# of the intraday_df due to the datetimes/dates merging
merged_df = pd.merge(intraday_df, daily_df, how='outer', on='time')
print(merged_df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.merge_asof` allows you to easily do a merge like this.

```
yesterdays_high = (intraday_df.resample('B', on='time')['current_intraday_high'].max()
                              .shift()
                              .rename('yesterdays_high')
                              .reset_index())

merged_df = pd.merge_asof(intraday_df, yesterdays_high)
print(merged_df)
```

Output:

```
                  time  current_intraday_high  yesterdays_high
0  2022-02-11 09:00:00                      1              NaN
1  2022-02-11 10:00:00                      2              NaN
2  2022-02-11 11:00:00                      3              NaN
3  2022-02-11 12:00:00                      4              NaN
4  2022-02-11 13:00:00                      5              NaN
5  2022-02-14 09:00:00                      6              5.0
6  2022-02-14 10:00:00                      7              5.0
7  2022-02-14 11:00:00                      8              5.0
8  2022-02-14 12:00:00                      9              5.0
9  2022-02-14 13:00:00                     10              5.0
10 2022-02-15 09:00:00                     11             10.0
11 2022-02-15 10:00:00                     12             10.0
12 2022-02-15 11:00:00                     13             10.0
13 2022-02-15 12:00:00                     14             10.0
14 2022-02-15 13:00:00                     15             10.0
15 2022-02-16 09:00:00                     16             15.0
16 2022-02-16 10:00:00                     17             15.0
17 2022-02-16 11:00:00                     18             15.0
18 2022-02-16 12:00:00                     19             15.0
19 2022-02-16 13:00:00                     20             15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your already existing code, you can `map` the shifted values:

```
intraday_df['yesterdays_high'] = (intraday_df['time']
 .dt.date
 .map(daily_df['daily_high'] 
      .set_axis(daily_df['time'].shift(-1)))
 )
```

If you don't have all days and really want to `map` the real previous business day:

```
intraday_df['yesterdays_high'] = (intraday_df['time']
 .dt.date
 .map(daily_df['daily_high']
      .set_axis(daily_df['time'].add(pd.offsets.BusinessDay())))
)
```

Output:

```
                  time  current_intraday_high  yesterdays_high
0  2022-02-11 09:00:00                      1              NaN
1  2022-02-11 10:00:00                      2              NaN
2  2022-02-11 11:00:00                      3              NaN
3  2022-02-11 12:00:00                      4              NaN
4  2022-02-11 13:00:00                      5              NaN
5  2022-02-14 09:00:00                      6              5.0
6  2022-02-14 10:00:00                      7              5.0
7  2022-02-14 11:00:00                      8              5.0
8  2022-02-14 12:00:00                      9              5.0
9  2022-02-14 13:00:00                     10              5.0
10 2022-02-15 09:00:00                     11             10.0
11 2022-02-15 10:00:00                     12             10.0
12 2022-02-15 11:00:00                     13             10.0
13 2022-02-15 12:00:00                     14             10.0
14 2022-02-15 13:00:00                     15             10.0
15 2022-02-16 09:00:00                     16             15.0
16 2022-02-16 10:00:00                     17             15.0
17 2022-02-16 11:00:00                     18             15.0
18 2022-02-16 12:00:00                     19             15.0
19 2022-02-16 13:00:00                     20             15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `.dt.date` as an index to join two frames together on the same days. As of previous day `hight_price`, we can apply `shift` on `daily_df`:

```
intra_date = intraday_df['time'].dt.date
daily_date = daily_df['time'].dt.date

answer = intraday_df.set_index(intra_date).join(
    daily_df.set_index(daily_date)['daily_high'].shift()
).reset_index(drop=True)
```