# Find highest high, considering today's rolling intraday high, and the previous day's high

Tags: python, pandas, ohlc

Building off of my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020352/find-yesterdays-high-price-by-merging-two-dfs-on-datetime-and-date-columns), what I need to do now is find the `rolling().max()` or rolling max price for each individual day. What I need is to create a column that contains the MAX of either yesterday's highest high price, or today's rolling highest high price. This is done using intraday data which makes it a bit tricky, and the dates/times change as time goes on/as you progress down the rows.

So considering this dataset:

[image: currentDataset]

...how can I get this added column:

[image: desiredDataset]

As you can see, when the `current_intraday_high` price becomes greater than it's `yesterdays_highest_high` price, the `current_intraday_high` becomes the new highest high for the current day. Even if the price drops for the rest of the day, the highest high is still "remembered" for that day, so a `rolling(x).max()` could work here, however that `x` is dynamic as you progress throughout the day.

If you were to somehow know the current `bar`'s number since the beginning of the current day (like at 9:00, `x` would equal 0, at 10:00 `x` would equal 1, at 11:00 `x` would equal 2, etc. And then reset when the date changes, that could work for using `rolling(x).max()`, but not sure of what the solution is here.)

Another thing to notice is the added desired column only pertains to the current date/dat, so it will only ever have:

1. The current date's `current_intraday_high` rolling highest high, or
2. the value in `yesterdays_highest_high`, whichever is bigger.

And if a new `current_intraday_high` is reached today, that becomes the rolling max to "beat" (so to speak) for the rest of that day. When a new day starts, it starts over again. Have to assume that each day will have a different number of rows, not just 5 for each day like I have here. Some may have 50 rows for the day, some may be 40, completely random.

Here is a reproducible code with dataset as shown:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


###################################################
# CREATE MOCK INTRADAY DATAFRAME
###################################################
intraday_date_time = [
    "2022-02-11 09:00:00",
                "2022-02-11 10:00:00",
                "2022-02-11 11:00:00",
                "2022-02-11 12:00:00",
                "2022-02-11 13:00:00",
    "2022-02-14 09:00:00",
                "2022-02-14 10:00:00",
                "2022-02-14 11:00:00",
                "2022-02-14 12:00:00",
                "2022-02-14 13:00:00",
    "2022-02-15 09:00:00",
                "2022-02-15 10:00:00",
                "2022-02-15 11:00:00",
                "2022-02-15 12:00:00",
                "2022-02-15 13:00:00",
    "2022-02-16 09:00:00",
                "2022-02-16 10:00:00",
                "2022-02-16 11:00:00",
                "2022-02-16 12:00:00",
                "2022-02-16 13:00:00",
    "2022-02-17 09:00:00",
                "2022-02-17 10:00:00",
                "2022-02-17 11:00:00",
                "2022-02-17 12:00:00",
                "2022-02-17 13:00:00",
]
intraday_date_time = pd.to_datetime(intraday_date_time)
intraday_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": intraday_date_time,
        "current_intraday_high": [1,2,3,2,1,
                                  3,4,5,4,3,
                                  5,6,7,6,5,
                                  7,8,9,8,7,
                                  5,6,7,6,5,
                                  ],
        "yesterdays_highest_high": [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,
                                    3,3,3,3,3,
                                    5,5,5,5,5,
                                    7,7,7,7,7,
                                    5,5,5,5,5,
                                    ],
    },
)
print(intraday_df)
# intraday_df.to_csv('intraday_df.csv', index=True)


###################################################
# CREATE THE ROLLING DAILY HIGHEST HIGH COLUMN
###################################################
# Attempt, not working obviously
intraday_df['current_highest_high'] = np.where(intraday_df['current_intraday_high'] > intraday_df['yesterdays_highest_high'],
                                               intraday_df['current_intraday_high'], np.nan)

print(intraday_df)
```

I'll be back tomorrow night (11:00 PM Central-ish) to review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
intraday_df.assign(current_highest_high=intraday_df
                                   .groupby(intraday_df.time.dt.normalize()).cummax()
                                   [["current_intraday_high","yesterdays_highest_high"]]
                                   .max(axis=1, skipna=False))
```

Output:

```
+----+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+
|    | time                |   current_intraday_high |   yesterdays_highest_high |   current_highest_high |
|----+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------|
|  0 | 2022-02-11 09:00:00 |                       1 |                       nan |                    nan |
|  1 | 2022-02-11 10:00:00 |                       2 |                       nan |                    nan |
|  2 | 2022-02-11 11:00:00 |                       3 |                       nan |                    nan |
|  3 | 2022-02-11 12:00:00 |                       2 |                       nan |                    nan |
|  4 | 2022-02-11 13:00:00 |                       1 |                       nan |                    nan |
|  5 | 2022-02-14 09:00:00 |                       3 |                         3 |                      3 |
|  6 | 2022-02-14 10:00:00 |                       4 |                         3 |                      4 |
|  7 | 2022-02-14 11:00:00 |                       5 |                         3 |                      5 |
|  8 | 2022-02-14 12:00:00 |                       4 |                         3 |                      5 |
|  9 | 2022-02-14 13:00:00 |                       3 |                         3 |                      5 |
| 10 | 2022-02-15 09:00:00 |                       5 |                         5 |                      5 |
| 11 | 2022-02-15 10:00:00 |                       6 |                         5 |                      6 |
| 12 | 2022-02-15 11:00:00 |                       7 |                         5 |                      7 |
| 13 | 2022-02-15 12:00:00 |                       6 |                         5 |                      7 |
| 14 | 2022-02-15 13:00:00 |                       5 |                         5 |                      7 |
| 15 | 2022-02-16 09:00:00 |                       7 |                         7 |                      7 |
| 16 | 2022-02-16 10:00:00 |                       8 |                         7 |                      8 |
| 17 | 2022-02-16 11:00:00 |                       9 |                         7 |                      9 |
| 18 | 2022-02-16 12:00:00 |                       8 |                         7 |                      9 |
| 19 | 2022-02-16 13:00:00 |                       7 |                         7 |                      9 |
| 20 | 2022-02-17 09:00:00 |                       5 |                         5 |                      5 |
| 21 | 2022-02-17 10:00:00 |                       6 |                         5 |                      6 |
| 22 | 2022-02-17 11:00:00 |                       7 |                         5 |                      7 |
| 23 | 2022-02-17 12:00:00 |                       6 |                         5 |                      7 |
| 24 | 2022-02-17 13:00:00 |                       5 |                         5 |                      7 |
+----+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Looks good! Will test when I get home tonight and mark as correct. Thanks!